# .NET postback blank page

Tags: .net, user-controls, postback

I am making a page on which products can be ordered.
This page contains an unset amount of products and each product has several delivery weeks. For each of this delivery week, you can enter the amount, the discount amount and the discount type.

I made a usercontrol to add the week and its textboxes. But this means that, when we have 100 products and each product can be ordered in 4 different weeks, the page contains (100*4)*3 = 1200 controls (or 400 usercontrols with 3 textfields).

e.g.

```
PRODUCTDESCRIPTION 1
[week a    amount  amount_discount discount_type] --> this is 1 usercontrol
week b    amount  amount_discount discount_type
week c    amount  amount_discount discount_type
week d    amount  amount_discount discount_type
PRODUCTDESCRIPTION 2
week a    amount  amount_discount discount_type
week b    amount  amount_discount discount_type
week c    amount  amount_discount discount_type
week d    amount  amount_discount discount_type
```

After all data has been entered, the user can submit the form.

When we sell 60 products, all works fine. The postback saves everything to the database and I get to see the thank you page. However when I have 112 products (I don't know the correct amount of when it goes wrong) and I submit the page, everything goes wrong: nothing goes into the database. Instead I stay on the same page but it goes blank. The response.write in the page load is not written either.

Does anybody know what the reason of this might be? Is there some kind of limit on the amount of usercontrols or is the viewstate running full or what could it be?

You can easily recreate this by creating a new webform, then add a panel and a button on the aspx page and in the page load, add the following:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("here")

        If Not Page.IsPostBack Then
            For i As Int64 = 0 To 1000
                Dim txt As New TextBox
                pnlTest.Controls.Add(txt)
            Next
        End If
```

After the page is loaded, click the button. You'll end up with a blank page.

*edit: on a different server the above test does not show a problem ... hmm